# Why won't my objective c implementation file recognize my import statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, import, cs193p

Here is my header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <PolygonShape.h>

@interface Controller : NSObject {
    IBOutlet UIButton *decreaseButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *increaseButton;
    IBOutlet UILabel *numberOfSidesLabel;
    //IBOutlet PolygonShape *shape;
}
- (IBAction)decrease;
- (IBAction)increase;
@end
```

Here is my implementation file

```
#import "Controller.h"

@implementation Controller
- (IBAction)decrease {
    //shape.numberOfSides -= 1;
}

- (IBAction)increase {
    //shape.numberOfSides += 1;
}
@end
```

Why am I getting the following error on my `#import "Controller.h"` line?

```
error: PolygonShape.h: No such file or directory
```

The PolygonShape.h and .m files are in the same project and in the same directory as the Controller class.

Comment: Have you made sure that the PolygonShape file is added to the target?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The angle braces (`<>`) mean that the file is in a standard include path, such as /usr/include or /System/Library/Frameworks. To import a file relative to the current directory, you need to use double-quotes like you do in `#import "Controller.h"`.

Comment: I though that too, but I just tried it with angle brackets on a local file and it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

System header files use <>. Your header files should use "".

So it should be:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PolygonShape.h"
```

And you might want to use @class PolygonShape in your header file and do the import in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you import class A in B and then import class B in A you will get this error